# Какая структура конструктора в Jquery правильная

Tags: javascript, jquery

Объясните чем отличаются две структуры и какую лучше использовать в проектах?

Стандартный конструктор

```
var DetectorFunc = function () {
  this.init();
};
DetectorFunc.protorype = {
  init: function() {

  },
  add: function() {

  },
}
```

В моем проекте встречается такая структура

```
$$.DetectorFunc = new (function()
{
  this.add = function() {

  }

  this.init = function() {

  }

  this.init();
})();
```

В глобальной среде

```
1 вариант
----------------------------------
var detector = new DetectorFunc();
detector.add();

2 вариант
----------------------------------
$$.DetectorFunc.add();
```

Comment: Что-то во втором варианте вызов `add` какой-то подозрительный. И что такое `$$`?

Comment: $$ - я так понимаю, что это был стандарт для названия таких функций-объектов, т.е $$.FuncObjectName = new(function(){ })();

Comment: Ага, вы поменяли код. Теперь немного понятнее. В данном случае $$.DetectorFunc - это синглтон, объект. Но не функция-конструктор. А первый вариант - это функция конструктор (что-то вроде класса). Соответственно сравнивать их напрямую нельзя. Для каждого - своя роль.